# WPFToolkit Calendar Change Language

Tags: wpf, localization, calendar, runtime

How can I change calendar control's language from WPFToolkit library at runtime?

**XAML:**

```
<toolkit:Calendar Style="{StaticResource CalendarStyle1}"/>
```

**C#**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    App.LanguageChanged += App_LanguageChanged;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(App.Language.ToString());
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(App.Language.ToString());
}

private void App_LanguageChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(App.Language.ToString()); ;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(App.Language.ToString());
}
```

This only allow to localize calendar at app start, but after App.Language changes, calendar's localization not changing - it's need to restart the app.

Comment: If it is importnant, I've overrided the calendar's template in style CalendarStyle1

Comment: upd: I've noticed that calendar's localization also changing after selected date changing, but I need to do it automatically and without selected data changing. Maybe, there are need some updating or refreshing of calendar?